# Async retrieving data from Firebase Firestore Kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to store the data from firebase into a variable to be used later on but it keeps returning a null result. I understand that this is because it takes time to retrieve data from the database and i should use async/coroutines to do so but i cant for the life of me figure out how to do so.

```
private suspend fun retrieveDataFromFireBase() {
    // Create a reference to the cities collection
    val usersCollection = db.collection("users")
    // Create a query against the collection.
    val query = usersCollection.orderBy("points", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(10)
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            for (document in documents) {
                userNameStorage.add(document.data?.getValue("fullname").toString())
                pointsStorage.add(document.data?.getValue("points").toString())
                if (document.contains("imageUrl")) {
                    imageURL.add(document.data?.getValue("imageUrl").toString())
                } else {
                    imageURL.add("null")
                }

            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.w("error5566", "Error getting documents: ", exception)
        }
    }
}
```

can someone please help me out

Comment: You need to use the Firebase Ktx library to have access to using coroutines instead of callback listeners. https://dev.to/rosariopfernandes/using-kotlin-extension-functions-and-coroutines-with-firebase-j0k

Comment: You will want to take the Task returned by `get()` and convert that into a deferrable using the library provided by Kotlin: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services